# R shiny + function and code outside the ui and server functions

Tags: r, function, shiny

I would like to know if it is possible to write code outside the ui and serve functions of a shiny app ?

I have a big script which involves several functions, so I would like to preserve the general structure of the pipeline when coding the shinyApp. These functions would take reactive values as parameters.

Thanks.

Comment: Yes it is. You can just place them outside of the functions in the same script.

Comment: All right, so that's not the reason my app doesn't work. Thank you :)

Comment: If you are actually having trouble with code, it's best to include a minimal [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) that makes it clear what's going on. This question right now it a bit too vague to be useful.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the comment for your question: the code in the `app.R` file can be placed outside the `server`/`ui` functions and will be accessible by the shiny application.

You could read more in [Scoping rules for Shiny apps article](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/scoping.html), headlines:

- All objects created outside server/ui functions is shared across all users sessions (within the same R process)
- Objects created in `server` function are accessible only for current session